# Excel file corrupts when images are pasted onto a spreadsheet with images

Tags: excel, openpyxl, python-3.7

The problem:
Using python to add images to excel.
When running the code on a blank excel file for the first time, the code works great and the images are pasted onto the spreadsheet without any problem.
2nd time running the exact same code, the excel file corrupts.

This seems to be a problem with pasting images onto spreadsheets when there is already an image there.

Here is the code:
images: test1.png, test2.png

```
import os
import openpyxl


print(os.getcwd())

file_name = 'a.xlsx'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_name)   # open exist excel file
ws = wb["Sheet1"]  # set the active sheet
sheet = wb.active
ws['a2'].value = 11112
wb.save(file_name)


#------------------attach image to the cell and change the image size-----
# ws = wb.worksheets[0]  # default the sheet1

img = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image('test2.png')
img.height = 238
img.width = 356
ws.add_image(img, 'B6')
img = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image('test1.png')
img.height = 238
img.width = 356
ws.add_image(img, 'I6')  # add image to the file at location L41

wb.save(file_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two saves giving an IO error.
You don't need to save until the end so the 1st save can be deleted

```
import os
import openpyxl


print(os.getcwd())

file_name = 'a.xlsx'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_name)   # open exist excel file
ws = wb["Sheet1"]  # set the active sheet
sheet = wb.active
ws['a2'].value = 11112
# wb.save(file_name)     # <----- Save 1 can be removed


#------------------attach image to the cell and change the image size-----
# ws = wb.worksheets[0]  # default the sheet1

img = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image('test2.png')
img.height = 238
img.width = 356
ws.add_image(img, 'B6')
img = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image('test1.png')
img.height = 238
img.width = 356
ws.add_image(img, 'I6')  # add image to the file at location L41

wb.save(file_name) # <----- Save 2 is the only one needed
```